# Using Dependency Injection in Custom Filter .net Core always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

When I am using the DI in TokenAuthorizeFilter, the _User always return null.Not only the _User, this is only an example of what I am encountered. I've tried different ways but still doesn't work.

I'm confused now, please tell me why. Thank you

```
public class BaseAuthorizeFilter : IAuthorizationFilter, IActionFilter
{
    public static ClaimsIdentity _User;
    public static IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

    public BaseAuthorizeFilter(UserResolverService userService, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _User = userService.GetUser();
        _accessor = accessor;
    }
}
...
```

UserResolverService.cs

```
public class UserResolverService : IUserResolverService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _context;

    public UserResolverService(IHttpContextAccessor context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public ClaimsIdentity GetUser()
    {
        return _context.HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        //await
    }
}

public interface IUserResolverService
{
    ClaimsIdentity GetUser();
}
```

TokenAuthorizeFilter.cs

```
public class TokenAuthorizeFilter : BaseAuthorizeFilter
{
    var identity = _User;
}
```

Sorry, I didn’t mentioned something in my question. I am calling a method in TokenAuthorizeFilter from another class so I defined it as static. Now I change my way writing it, and I found the answer from Microsoft’s website. Thanks a lot.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#ifilterfactory-implemented-on-your-attribute

Comment: Where are you registering your filter? Is it just `_User` that's null, or also `_accessor`?

Comment: Also the `_accessor` in Startup.cs: services.AddSingleton<TokenAuthorizeFilter>(); Do you mean this?

Comment: Why are you registering it as a singleton? That's very likely to be your problem.

Comment: sorry this should be right `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`
`services.AddSingleton<IUserResolverService, UserResolverService>();`

Comment: I think that's OK, but `BaseAuthorizeFilter ` should not be a singleton.

Comment: sorry, but I didn't register it as a singleton

Comment: You showed me this: `services.AddSingleton<TokenAuthorizeFilter>();`?

Comment: Prevent using any injected service from within the constructor of a component, as you do by calling `userService.GetUser()` inside the `BaseAuthorizeFilter` constructor. [Injection constructors should be simple](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/).

Comment: Check the answer, if it did not work, share us a reproduable project.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues in your post.

- You register `IUserResolverService` by `services.AddSingleton<IUserResolverService, UserResolverService>();`, but you inject `UserResolverService userService`,
- You should not define `ClaimsIdentity _User` as static, it should be request isolation

try to change like below:

```
    public class BaseAuthorizeFilter : IAuthorizationFilter, IActionFilter
{
    public ClaimsIdentity _User;
    public IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

    public BaseAuthorizeFilter(IUserResolverService userService, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _User = userService.GetUser();
        _accessor = accessor;
    }
```

- Check the difference between your `TokenAuthorizeFilter` and below code:

  ```
  public class TokenAuthorizeFilter : BaseAuthorizeFilter
  {
     public TokenAuthorizeFilter(IUserResolverService userService
         , IHttpContextAccessor accessor):base(userService, accessor)
    {
        var identity = _User;
    }
  }
  ```
- Register `TokenAuthorizeFilter` as `AddScoped`

  ```
      services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
      services.AddSingleton<IUserResolverService, UserResolverService>();
      services.AddScoped<TokenAuthorizeFilter>();
  ```